# PDF font remapping

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have a set PDF files with Identity-H encoded fonts, which means that the symbols shown don't match their codes, but there is a one-to-one correspondence between them.

So, basically it's a mapping problem. The questions is whether there are any free tools available (any OS) for the task of manual or semi-automated correction of font maps in PDF, preferably for Terminal, but GUI would also be acceptable.

There is [Infix PDF editor](http://www.iceni.com/) for Windows, which has a "remap fonts" option (see below), but it's for money and has no option to save the results of the remapping as PDF.

[image: infix]

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found so far is as follows:

- extract the font from the PDF-file with [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/);
- modify the map manually and export the font as ttf;
- add the ttf in Windows system-wide;
- open the PDF in [Infix PDF editor](http://www.iceni.com/) (its trial version is fine) and correct the map of the font;
- in Infix replace the font with the version corrected in FontForge;
- save the PDF (and optionally remove the watermark always created by the the trial version of Infix).

Better suggestions are welcome.